# How to invalidate ASP.NET cache if data changes in PostgreSql database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, caching, mono

ASP.NET/MONO MVC2 application standard ASP.NET Web cache is used to speed up database access:

```
string GetName() {
  // todo: dedect if data has changed and invalidate cache
  var name = (string)HttpContext.Current.Cache["Name"];
  if (name!=null)
    return name;
  name = db.Query("SELECT name from mydata");
  HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("Name", name);
  return name;
}
```

mydata can changed by other application.
In this case this method returns wrong data.
How to detect if data is changed and return fresh data from PostgreSql database in this case ?

It is OK to clear whole Web cache if mydata has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is likely with [`LISTEN` and `NOTIFY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-listen.html).

Have your app maintain a background worker with a persistent connection to the DB. In that connection, issue a `LISTEN name_changed`, then wait for notifications. If npgsql supports it it might offer a callback; otherwise you'll have to poll.

Add a trigger to the `name` table that issues a `NOTIFY name_changed`.

When your background worker gets the notification it can flush the cache.

You can even use the `NOTIFY` payload to invalidate only changed entries selectively.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like a lot of work. Is there a ready made solution for PostgreSql for this like SqlCacheDependency for MS SQL server ?

Comment: @Andrus I doubt it, but I don't use .NET so I wouldn't know for sure. There's usually lots more canned stuff for .NET + MS SQL Server for obvious reasons. An approach like the above should be pretty simple to implement; I've written similar code for Java and it's only taken a simple trigger and a couple of small-ish classes.

Comment: @Andrus See the "Working with notifications" section of http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html . You'd want to use the "Synchronous notifications" mode to avoid polling. Looks like it's really simple from npgsql.

Comment: ASP.NET cache is local to application. Thread may terminate if request is completed. How to implement background worker in this case ?. I posted question about it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12880143/how-to-create-background-worker-in-mono-net-mvc2-application-to-invalidate-post